# Failed to syntheis speech for the Bot Framework Web Chat

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, speech, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I'm having a go with speech for a BOT. I have been running through the Microsoft Tutorial found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/tutorial-voice-enable-your-bot-speech-sdk). I've taken the example Echo BOT example from there, found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/experimental/directline-speech/csharp_dotnetcore/02.echo-bot/README.md), as a basis so I can use it as a basis going forward. This has been successfully deployed to my Azure environment. Also in the tutorial, you run your Bot through the Direct Line Speech Client v1, everything works as expected when doing this.

I have looked at the [Bot Framework Web Chat speech notes](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/SPEECH.md) to get the Bot working using this as my channel. Here is my code for this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Web Chat: Browser-supported speech</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body { height: 100% }
      body { margin: 0 }
      #webchat {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
    <script>
         (async function () {

            window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
            directLine: createDirectLine({
                secret: '<My Direct Line secret>'
              }),
              language: 'en-US',
              webSpeechPonyfillFactory: await createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory({
                region: '<Speech cognitive service region>',
                subscriptionKey: '<Speech cognitive service key>'
              })
            }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
            document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
          })().catch(err => console.error(err));
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm able to get this working and I can do speech to text and text inputs and the contents is written back, but when it tries to do text to speech back I'm getting the following errors in the browser console:

```
POST https://<region>.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1 net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (Speak node can only be the root.)
webchat.js:1 Error: Failed to syntheis speech, server returned 400
    at webchat.js:1
    at c (webchat.js:1)
    at Generator._invoke (webchat.js:1)
    at Generator.e.<computed> [as next] (webchat.js:1)
    at n (webchat.js:1)
    at s (webchat.js:1)
```

I'm not quite sure if it is something in the script code or the Bot, let me know if you need any more detail. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is weird... I hosted a echo bot on Azure and just copy and paste your html code and did some config ,I tested on edge firefox and chrome but everything works well including tts calling : 
[image]

You can try it [here](https://hurytestftpapp.azurewebsites.net/) and check the config . Hope it helps .